# Different background depending on the category clicked

Tags: css, twig

I'm trying to have different classes depending on which category I'm in.

```
{% for u in utilisateur.getListCategories %}
    <div class="catPostIt">
        <a href="{{ path('categorie', {'id': u.id})}}">{{u.nom}}</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Heres the css :

```css
.catPostIt {
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: grey;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    margin: 5px;
}

.catPostIt a:active {
    background: linear-gradient(0.25turn,#974FA1, #FF2B6D); 
}
```

The active background only lasts for 0,5 sec and becomes grey again.

Is it because the page is reloading?

Comment: Active is when you "actively" have your mouse button down on the link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active. _When using a mouse, "activation" typically starts when the user presses down the primary mouse button._

Comment: Do you have something like the `activeCategory` somewhere out of your controller?

Comment: Change your selector to `:visited`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Thanks for the answer, indeed, :active is not what i'm looking for

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I do not have any activeCategory in any controller

Comment: @DarkBee I Thanks for the answer, i tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Is there pages under categories? Would you please share us some examples of URL of that app?

Comment: @DarkBee if OP wants something like an URL comparison this won’t be solvable only by css.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε true that, but as OP stated `The active background only lasts for 0,5 sec and becomes grey again` he/she should use `visited`. Alternating the colors should not be done by URL imho, but with an extra attribute e.g. `css_class` on the model `category`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Yes, I got one page that takes the id of the category and change her content depending on the category : https://127.0.0.1:8000/categorie/2

Comment: I tried here to get my category id and set active class to the current url, it doesn't work. But i think i'm close

Comment: `{{ app.request.pathinfo|slice(-1) }}
   <div class="catPostIt">
     <a class="{{ app.request.pathinfo|slice(-1) == "{{u.id}}" ? 'active' }}" href="{{path('categorie', {'id': u.id})}}">{{u.nom}} </a>
   </div> `

Comment: Hum, that is a really naive approach @auredev, what when you'll have the category `10`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have pages under the categories, where you'll also want the background to be applied on the link, then this could be a solution:

```html
{% for u in utilisateur.getListCategories %}
  <div class="catPostIt">      
    <a class="{{ app.request.pathinfo == path('categorie', {'id': u.id}) ? 'active' }}" 
       href="{{ path('categorie', {'id': u.id}) }}">
      {{u.nom}} 
    </a>    
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

```css
.catPostIt a.active {
    background: linear-gradient(0.25turn,#974FA1, #FF2B6D); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought I could simply check my category ID with the end of my url but there's probably a mismatch of types.

Comment: Probably there is somewhere the `currentCategoryId` that you could pass from your controller into the view, if you want to go that route but mind that slicing the URI with a `-1`  **will** return you `0` for the category `10`, so you are creating a bug for your future self there

Comment: Indeed ! That's not a great solution... But luckily this is an e-learning platform with only 5 different courses category. Should do the work ! Thanks again for your help